# Vin Check in Javascript to use for PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, vin

I'm kind of new to Javascript and I'm trying to figure out how this all works. I'm making a form in Adobe Acrobat Pro. On of the required fields for my customers is to enter a valid VIN (the Vehicle Indentification Number of your car).

The VIN is made up of 17 characters and beleive it or not, allmost 25% of all entered VIN by my clients has some sort of error. There is a VIN check that let's you check if the entered VIN is correct.

How to make a VIN check in Javascript so I can use it in Adobe?

Comment: what should you check for in your VIN validation?

Comment: Please let us know what you already tried, and how it failed. SO users cannot write your code for you.